# Is it possible to give beep sound using progress 4GL?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

Is it possible to give beep sound using progress 4gl? If yes can you please help to share a demo program which plays beep sound if any errors? I am new to progress and it will be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

take a look at the **BELL** statement

but you can not specifikate a sound file
it's the windows error sound

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you are using a Progress OpenEdge client that can use .Net classes, you can use the .Net console [beep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.beep):

```
System.Console:Beep().
```

To play any `wav` you can use the [SoundPlayer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.media.soundplayer) class:

```
def var o as System.Media.SoundPlayer.

o = new System.Media.SoundPlayer( 'c:\windows\media\chimes.wav' ).
o:PlaySync().
```